# Visual Studio Code crashes constantly when working with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Several times when working with a Jupyter Notebook on Visual Studio Code, the cell will get stuck at the [*] reading. It is impossible in this state to save my progress. This is happening in two different windows machines.

In both machines I tested, I'm using Python 3.8.2 32-bit on Visual Studio Code 1.46.1, on a Windows 10 PC with a core i5 processor desktop and 8 gb ram.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check if there is an existing bug? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+jupyter

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions about specific code. Try Super User for this question.

Answer (score -1):

- It means that your kernel is still running. You can manually stopping the kernel by pressing the stop button above, or `Ctrl+Shif+P`, `Python: Interrupt IPython Kernel`.
- If it doesn't work, try closing and reopening it.
- The problem may also be the error of your code. See if there is an infinite loop within the kernel.